# Reveal image over top another while scrolling

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, sticky

Currently have three images displayed below one another. I'm using Sticky-Kit to keep the top image in place while the rest are scrolled into view.
What I'd like to achieve though, is to keep the images below the top one hidden until they reach the bottom of the first image. In other words, there's only one image visible, and the next one covers it from the bottom to the top while scrolling. Not sure how to best approach this.

Further breakdown of what I'm trying to achieve:

1) Scroll until #pic1 is centered in the viewport, at which point it 'sticks' while scrolling continues.

2) As the user continues to scroll, #pic2 begins to raise up from the bottom of #pic1 until it fully covers #pic1. Prior to this happening, only #pic1 is visible.

3) When #pic2 has fully covered #pic1, #pic3 emerges from the bottom to cover #pic2

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var $ = jQuery.noConflict();
  
  $("#text").stick_in_parent({offset_top: 90});
  $("#pic1").stick_in_parent({offset_top: 90});
  $("#pic2").stick_in_parent({offset_top: 90});
  $("#pic3").stick_in_parent({offset_top: 90});
});
```

```css
#text {
  width:40%;
  float:right;
  background-color:white;
  height:500px;
  padding-top:173px;
  padding-left:50px;
}

#pic1 {
  position:relative;
  width:60%;
  height:500px;
  background-color:green;
}

#pic2 {
  position:relative;
  width:60%;
  height:500px;
  background-color:red;
}

#pic3 {
  position:relative;
  width:60%;
  height:500px;
  background-color:blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/leafo/sticky-kit/v1.1.2/jquery.sticky-kit.min.js"></script>

<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>

<div id="text" class="p2">
  <h2 id="bluetooth-header" class="header-title"><span>HEADER</span></h2>
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.nd enjoy your newly curated playlist from the palm of your hand.
</div>

<div id="pic1"></div>
<div id="pic2"></div>
<div id="pic3"></div>
```

[**codepen.io/anon/pen/JbQZwN**](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/JbQZwN)

Comment: **sidenote:** instead of copying the same CSS-rules for every image, it's more effective to give the images an extra class, all put all the rules that are the same for every image into that class -> *HTML:* `<div class="pic" id="pic1"></div>` ... *CSS:* `.pic {position:relative; width:60%; height:500px;} #pic1 {background-color:green;} #pic2 {background-color:red;}` ... *JS:* `$(".pic").stick_in_parent({offset_top:90});` (notice the same trick applied in the jQuery-selector). [**See this codepen**](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/PbrBmr) for the same code but clearly formatted

Comment: Let me see if I got this right: **(1)** You want only `#pic1` to be visible. **(2)** When user has scrolled to the bottom of `#pic1`, then `#pic1` hides and `#pic2` takes the place of `#pic1`. **(3)** Then, when user has scrolled to the bottom of `#pic2`, then `#pic2` hides and `#pic3` takes the place of `#pic2`. And so on if there are more pictures...

Comment: Correct -- sort of. Here's a better breakdown of what I'm hoping to achieve:

1) Scroll until #pic1 is centered in the viewport, at which point it 'sticks'
2) As the user continues to scroll, #pic2 begins to raise up from the bottom of #pic1 until it fully covers #pic1.
3) When #pic2 has fully covered #pic1, #pic3 emerges from the bottom to cover #pic2

Hope that helps!

Comment: Isn't that already what's happening?

Comment: With my current code, when the green box reaches the middle, you can see the red box below. I'm trying to have only the green box visible, with white space below it, and the red box 'grow' up from the bottom of the green box. Almost as if there was a fixed white box underneath the green one that covered any other boxes.

Comment: And you want the pics to scroll to the last pic, *before* the page scroll further down, *but without* having to scroll on the pics themselves (i.e. without having to put the cursor over the pics and then scroll only the pics)?

Comment: Correct -- I think I've successfully achieved that with Sticky-kit. Once the last image reaches the top, then the page continues to scroll.